# Is it possible to use StyledCellLabelProvider.COLORS_ON_SELECTION with a DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

I just found mention of how to keep background cell color even while hovering or selecting a row on a JFace TableViewer by using `StyledCellLabelProvider.COLORS_ON_SELECTION`. However, I am using a subclass of `StyledCellLabelProvider` - a `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider`.

Is there any way for me to use the `StyledCellLabelProvider.COLORS_ON_SELECTION` style bit? I don't see any constructors that take a style bit, and no method to set the style.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the flag but you can override the `DecoratingStyledCellLabelProvider.paint` method to simulate what it does:

```java
@Override
protected void paint(final Event event, final Object element)
{
  if ((event.detail & SWT.SELECTED) != 0)
   {
     event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;

     super.paint(event, element);

     event.detail |= SWT.SELECTED;
   }
  else
    super.paint(event, element);
}
```

This is just turning off the 'selected' flag during the paint so the row is treated as normal.

However I don't really recommend this (or COLORS_ON_SELECTION) as it does not work well on some platforms.

Comment: I know this is old, but can you elaborate more on which platforms it doesn't work for? I tried it using eclipse luna on windows 7 and it doesn't seem to be having any effect at all.

Comment: I haven't run this on Windows since the days of Windows Vista so I don't know how it behaves in more current Windows releases.